# Kohana 3.3 Auth: File Driver and Remember Flag

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, kohana

I am working on a very simple site with a few users and passwords. Using the ORM Driver for Auth seems like an overkill for what I want to achieve. However, I would need to implement a "remember me" feature so users do not have to login each time they open the browser if they do not want to.

The documentation for [Auth_File](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Auth_File#login) shows a login method with an optional third parameter called $remember, which is a boolean. Nevertheless, the description of the method states:

```
Attempt to log in a user by using an ORM object and plain-text password.
```

My question is: Can I have the remember me functionality using the File Driver for Auth, or will it only work using the ORM Driver?

Answer (score 0):

File driver doesn't support the autologin functionality